# Exact X-bits sized variables that support bitwise operations(c++)

Tags: c++, optimization, bit

I am trying to solve a problem using bit operations in C++ but i am really stuck. Please help me with the following query.

1) Is it possible to create variable's A and B which take exactly 100000bits in memory and on which an operation like A&B is valid?

2) Is there a fast way to generate B(100000bits) such that its first n bits are 0, last m bits are 0 and the remaining are 1's? (eg. if B was 10bits then a number like 0000011000)

Comment: Do you really mean 100000 bits (i.e. 12,500 bytes)? The answer to both your questions is that you should create a class and overload operators on that class to do the work you require. Or you could use existing classes to do the same.

Comment: @john how to overload the operator &?

Comment: Say your class is called Bit100000, then you simply write the function `Bit100000 operator&(const Bit100000& x, const Bit100000& y) { ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to 1, sure, this is the sort of things classes were meant for. Simply create a class containing 100,000 bits (about 12.5K) and override the `operator&` method (the binary one, not the address-of operator).

A good start would be (say we have two integers holding the bitmask):

```
BigBits BigBits::operator &(const BigBits &that) const {
    BigBits bb(*this);
    bb.array[0] = this->array[0] & that.array[0];
    bb.array[1] = this->array[1] & that.array[1];
    return bb;
}
```

This is untested but should give you the basic idea. In order to test it, I'd have to code up quite a bit, including constructors, destructors, assignments and so forth, when that really should be *your* task :-)

In answer to two, that's also easy. The only trick bits are the two edge bytes, all the internal bytes can just be set to all 1 bits.

In order to set the edge bytes, you use a bit of division and modulo with the number of bits in a byte and then use bitmasks to set them. The bitmasks would be `0x80`, `0xc0`, `0xe0`, `0xf0`, `0xf8` and so on, with each subsequent value adding another 1 bit.

Then you would use `bitmask[bitpos % 8]` in its various forms to set the edge bytes, the array indexes of which would be `bitpos / 8`.

Comment: Can you give a little example for this please.

Comment: @YashSingla, I've given a sample piece of code to get you going but I don't really feel the need to provide a complete working solution. Well, not without being paid for it of course :-)

Comment: Not only untested but wrong. You're allocating memory for some reason, and then you should say `return *bb;`, although that would be a memory leak.

Comment: @john, you could always have fixed the code yourself rather than pointing out the errors, this is supposed to be a community after all :-) I _think_ the new version is correct but I'm open to suggestions if you're so inclined.